# Replacing Consecutive Values in Delimited File

Tags: regex, unix, sed, aix

The ultimate objective is to replace all instances of ^NULL^ with ^^.  For this question, to increase readability, I'll try to replace ^NULL^ with ^fred^.  Here is my test data.

```
/usr/redbrick_dir $ cat temp
a^NULL^b^c^
e^NULL^NULL^f^
g^h^i^NULL^
```

This is what I expect to work.

```
/usr/redbrick_dir $ cat temp | sed "s/\^NULL\^/\^fred\^/g"
a^fred^b^c^
e^fred^NULL^f^
g^h^i^fred^
```

Note that in line 2, only the first instance of ^NULL^ is replaced.  However, if I run the command with only one delimiter,

```
/usr/redbrick_dir $ cat temp | sed "s/NULL\^/fred\^/g"
a^fred^b^c^
e^fred^fred^f^
g^h^i^fred^
```

I get the desired results.  I also get those results if I only use the trailing delimiter.  The question is, why does this command only replace the first instance of ^NULL^ ?

```
cat temp | sed "s/\^NULL\^/\^fred\^/g"
```

**Edit starts here**

Here is what happened when I tried a couple of the answers posted below.

```
cat temp | sed "s/(?<=\^)NULL(?=\^)/fred/g"
a^NULL^b^c^
e^NULL^NULL^f^
g^h^i^NULL^

cat temp | sed ":a s/\^NULL^/^fred^/;ta"
sed: 0602-417 The label :a s/\^NULL^/^fred^/;ta is greater than eight characters.
```

I'll have to check out the link provided by Utopik.

Answer (score 2):

> why does this command only replace the first instance of ^NULL^ ?

Because the expression doesn't match the second `^NULL^` in the second line, after the expression finds the first`^NULL^`, it now tries to find a match at the character right after `^`:

```
e^NULL^ NULL^f^
       ^
   it is now trying to find a match here but there is no ^NULL^ here, there is NULL^ only.
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lY3iJ2)

I don't know if `sed` supports lookbehinds or lookaheads but if it did, then I would do the replacement like this:

```
cat temp | sed "s/(?<=\^)NULL(?=\^)/fred/g"
```

Or in your case replace `fred` with empty string of course.

Answer (score 2):

*Tested with GNU sed*

First, you can remove some backslash : `sed "s/\^NULL^/^fred^/g"` without any change (`^` has no meaning but at start of regex)

Then, sed will match `^NULL^` and no character from that match can be reused for another match. So, it can't match the second `^NULL^` but only `NULL^`, that is why it doesnt work.

You can do it that way :

`sed ":a s/\^NULL^/^fred^/;ta"`

Why ? Because it will substitute the first `^NULL^`, then **restarting the substitution** over and over until no more substitution happens and, because it's a new cycle of substitution, every character can be matched

```
$ cat temp

a^NULL^b^c^
e^NULL^NULL^NULL^NULL^NULL^NULL^NULL^NULL^NULL^f^
g^h^i^NULL^

$ cat temp | sed ":a s/\^NULL^/^fred^/;ta"

a^fred^b^c^
e^fred^fred^fred^fred^fred^fred^fred^fred^fred^f^
g^h^i^fred^
```

it's ok.

( lots of good resources : http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/tutorials/ )

Answer (score 2):

```
There are two different scenarios:-

1) In First sed command it is like that
sed "s/\^NULL\^/\^fred\^/g"
```

When it is coming to the second line. It is searching two string as first one is ^NULL^ and second one is NULL^. so here it is unmatched. and because of that it is not replacing the same. For example how sed is searching the word
                Search word          Replace word
    found       ^Null^               ^fred^
    Not found    Null^

```
2) In second sed command it is like that sed "s/NULL\^/fred\^/g"
```

here it is only searching the word Null^ and replacing with fred^ . So it is matching the word correctly.